# Creating JavaScript prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple prototype in JavaScript that removes a character from a string (like Python's strip).  This may well exist already in JavaScript, but I can't find it and this is more of an exercise for me than a replacement for something that already exists.

```
function strip(chars) {
    this.replace(chars,"");
}

String.prototype.strip=strip;

var wrong = "Hellow";

alert(wrong.strip("w"));
```

When I run this code, the alert says "Undefined".  My suspicion is the `this.` in the function but not sure.  I've also made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/rapxM/

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return), so that the result of the operation is *returned*:

```
function strip(chars) {
   return this.replace(chars,"");
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rapxM/1/

Notice that your code does not remove all characters, it does only remove the *first occurrence*. If you want to remove *all* characters, use:

```
function strip(chars) {
   return this.split(chars).join('');
}
```

- [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) splits the string in smaller pieces, based on the given argument (returned value: array).
- [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is an array method, which concatenates the array (returned value: string)

Comment: Thanks!  I knew about the one occurrence, just wanted to get prototypes working.  +1 for example and will set as answer when I hit the timer.

Comment: Just note that Python's `strip` doesn't remove occurrences from the middle of the string (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). Don't know what @jdborg actually wants.

Comment: If he wants to emulate Python's `strip` method, he can either switch to a Regular Expression, or trim the characters in two loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same behavior as Python's `strip`, you should only remove characters from the start and end of the string. Here is a solution with regular expressions that accomplishes this:

```
function strip(chars, wholeString) {
    if (wholeString)
        chars = "(" + chars + ")*";
    else
        chars = "[" + chars + "]*";
    var pattern = "^" + chars + "|" + chars + "$";
    return this.replace(new RegExp(pattern, "g"),"");
}
```

If `wholeString` is set to `true`, it will treat `chars` as a block of characters that have to occur together (your question seemed to ask for that), while if not set (the default), each character in `chars` will be removed on its own (like in Python). Use it like this:

```
String.prototype.strip=strip;

var str = "ababccabcccbbab";
document.write(str.strip("ab"));       // -> "ccabccc"
document.write(str.strip("ab", true)); // -> "ccabcccbb"
```

Note that `ab` is not removed from the middle of `str`. In the first call, `a` and `b` are treated separately, so `bb` is also stripped.